# How to make enemy follow player

Tags: python, tkinter

I found information about pygame, but i cant interpret this in tkinter.
icons - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcRvh.jpg
pastebin - https://pastebin.com/ykUzj9Pc

```py
def key_pressed(event):
    global e
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        move_wrap(player, (0, -step))
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        move_wrap(player, (0, step))
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        move_wrap(player, (-step, 0))
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        move_wrap(player, (step, 0))
    check_move()
    # for enemy in enemies:
    #     direction = enemy[1]() # вызвать функцию перемещения у "врага"
    #     move_wrap(enemy[0], direction) # произвести  перемещение 
    #     print(e)
    for enemy in enemies:
        direction = enemy[1]()
        move_wrap(enemy[0], direction)
        list_ = [(step, 0), (-step, 0), (0, step), (0, -step)]
        predictions = []
        for i in list_:
            predictions.append([canvas.coords(enemy[0])[0] + i[0], canvas.coords(enemy[0])[1] + i[1]])
        for i in predictions:
            if i[0] - canvas.coords(player)[0] > i[1] - canvas.coords(player)[1]:
                if predictions.index(i) == 1:
                    move_wrap(enemy[0], (step, 0))
                elif predictions.index(i) == 2:
                    move_wrap(enemy[0], (-step, 0))
                elif predictions.index(i) == 3:
                    move_wrap(enemy[0], (0, step))
                elif predictions.index(i) == 4:
                    move_wrap(enemy[0], (0, -step))
        predictions.clear()
```

I have a list with enemies. In this list i have tuple with (enemy, random_move function).

Comment: That’s a bit of a broad question. Do you have a basic algorithm, pseudocode, anything?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ykUzj9Pc @AMC

Comment: What is that? Is it your entire program?

Comment: Yes, it is.1234

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I was specifically asking about the whole have an enemy follow the player thing.

Comment: I was thinking about subtracting x player and enemy and y player and enemy but how can I link the selection, honestly, I don't understand how to do it almost at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow `player` you have to calculate vector between `enemy` and `player`, and normalize this vector (so its lenght will be 1), and then you can multiplciate it by enemy's speed to get what distance it has to move

```
player_x, player_y = 0, 0
enemy_x,  enemy_y  = 100, 100


diff_x = player_x - enemy_x
diff_y = player_y - enemy_y

distance = (diff_x**2 + diff_y**2)**0.5  # Pythagoras: a**2 + b**2 = c**2

normal_x = diff_x/distance
normal_y = diff_y/distance

print(normal_x, normal_y)

enemy_speed = 5

enemy_move_x = enemy_speed * normal_x
enemy_move_y = enemy_speed * normal_y

print(enemy_move_x, enemy_move_y)
```

You may have to also check if `distance` is not zero because you may get `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

---

**EDIT:** Minimal working example - use keys `WASD` to move green circle and red circle will follow.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def follow(player_x, player_y, enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_speed=5):
    diff_x = player_x - enemy_x
    diff_y = player_y - enemy_y

    distance = (diff_x**2 + diff_y**2)**0.5  # Pythagoras: a**2 + b**2 = c**2

    if distance <= enemy_speed:
        return diff_x, diff_y

    normal_x = diff_x/distance
    normal_y = diff_y/distance

    enemy_move_x = enemy_speed * normal_x
    enemy_move_y = enemy_speed * normal_y

    return enemy_move_x, enemy_move_y

def on_key_press(event):
    global player_move_x
    global player_move_y

    if event.char == 'w':
        player_move_y -= 5
    if event.char == 's':
        player_move_y += 5
    if event.char == 'a':
        player_move_x -= 5
    if event.char == 'd':
        player_move_x += 5

def on_key_release(event):
    global player_move_x
    global player_move_y

    if event.char == 'w':
        player_move_y -= -5
    if event.char == 's':
        player_move_y += -5
    if event.char == 'a':
        player_move_x -= -5
    if event.char == 'd':
        player_move_x += -5

def update_game():
    global player_x
    global player_y
    global enemy_x
    global enemy_y

    player_x += player_move_x
    player_y += player_move_y
    canvas.move(player_id, player_move_x, player_move_y)

    enemy_move_x, enemy_move_y = follow(player_x, player_y, enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_speed)
    enemy_x += enemy_move_x
    enemy_y += enemy_move_y
    canvas.move(enemy_id, enemy_move_x, enemy_move_y)

    root.after(100, update_game)

# --- main ---

player_x = 250
player_y = 250
player_move_x = 0
player_move_y = 0

enemy_x = random.randint(0, 500)
enemy_y = random.randint(0, 500)
enemy_speed = 5

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg='gray')
canvas.pack()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_key_release)

player_id = canvas.create_oval(player_x-5, player_y-5, player_x+5, player_y+5, fill='green')
enemy_id = canvas.create_oval(enemy_x-5, enemy_y-5, enemy_x+5, enemy_y+5, fill='red')

update_game()

root.mainloop()
```